# shelve: db type could not be determined

Tags: python, python-3.4, shelve

I am using Pycharm. First of all whenever any module is imported in Pycharm. The complete import line fades out. But in case of `import shelve` doesn't fade out. Also when I run the file i get following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhimanyuaryan/PycharmProjects/shelve/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    s = shelve.open("file.dat")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/shelve.py", line 239, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/dbm/__init__.py", line 88, in open
    raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
 dbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

Here's my code:

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open("file.dat")

s["first"] = (1182, 234, 632, 4560)
s["second"] = {"404": "file is not present", "googling": "Google to search your content"}
s[3] = ["abhilasha", "jyoti", "nirmal"]

s.sync()

print(s["first"])
print(s["second"])
print(s[3])
```

Comment: So what DB type is `file.dat` supposed to be?  Does it exist?  Apparently this is what's causing PyCharm problems here, though it's not entirely clear why.

Comment: I wrote into a dat file using pickle and it wrote into that file. I still don't get what's the problem in this case n Yes file exits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OP explains in a comment that `'file.dat'` was created by `pickle` -- and that's the problem!  `pickle` **doesn't** use any DB format -- it uses its own!  Create `file.dat` with `shelve` in the first place (i.e run `shelve` when `file.dat` doesn't exist yet and save the stuff into it) and you'll be fine.

OP in comment: "I still don't get what's the problem in this case".  Answer: the problem is that `pickle` does **not** create a file in any of the DB formats `shelve` can use.  Use a single module for serializing and deserializing -- either just `pickle`, or, just `shelve` -- and it will work SO much better:-).

Answer (score 1):

There is one bug with anydb https://bugs.python.org/issue13007 that could not use the right identification for `gdbm` files.

So if you are trying to open a valid gdbm file with shelve and is thorwing that error use this instead:

```
    mod = __import__("gdbm")
    file = shelve.Shelf(mod.open(filename, flag))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the file extension.
Do as follows:
`

```
import shelve

s = shelve.open("file")

s["first"] = (1182, 234, 632, 4560)
s["second"] = {"404": "file is not present", "googling": "Google to search your content"}
s[3] = ["abhilasha", "jyoti", "nirmal"]

s.sync()

print(s["first"])
print(s["second"])
print(s[3])
```

`
It is important to note that if the shelf file was somewhere else you need to add dir name too